# Opening the 80 port on a Debian WSL to set up a small database

Tags: python-3.x, linux, http, python-requests, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to setup a automated Python trading bot in this project. I have cloned the repo to the WSL machine (Debian OS) and started to execute the main.

There is a logger strategy on the project which returns the current price of a given pair (ex BTC_EUR) that I ran successfully.

The next step is to import price data on a given time period and save it on a local database to perform analysis and backtesting. But running the import strategy returns the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 160, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 84, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 74, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1260, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1306, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1255, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1030, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 970, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 187, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 172, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3ec7c8eeb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/datasets (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3ec7c8eeb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 81, in <module>
    importer = Importer(exchange, period_start, period_end, interval)
  File "/home/chrisd/repos/cryptobot/services/importer.py", line 16, in __init__
    'currency': '/api/currencies/'+self.exchange.currency.lower(), 'asset': '/api/currencies/'+self.exchange.asset.lower()})
  File "/home/chrisd/repos/cryptobot/api/rest.py", line 91, in create
    response = self.post(self.serialize(data))
  File "/home/chrisd/repos/cryptobot/api/rest.py", line 72, in post
    return self.query(method="post", data=json.dumps(self.serialize(data)), headers=self.build_headers(headers))
  File "/home/chrisd/repos/cryptobot/api/rest.py", line 32, in query
    response = http_method(self.build_url(self.resource_name, iri), data=data, headers=headers).json()
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chrisd/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/datasets (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f3ec7c8eeb8>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

From what I understand, the script cannot establish a HTTP connection with my linux machine on port 80.

Here is what I get when I type the `ss -lt` command:

```
State          Recv-Q          Send-Q                   Local Address:Port                   Peer Address:Port
```

Obviously there is not sign of the 80 port there.
There is no firewall (UFW) installed, and I could not find the linux command to open a particular port in this case.
Any ideas on how to open the 80 port on WSL to establish the HTTP connection and set up the database?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ss` without any arguments just shows established connections.  To get listening TCP ports, use `ss -lt`.  What does that show?  (Edit question with results).  Thanks!

Comment: Also, just to confirm - Where is the Python import script running?  Is it in WSL, or is it on the Windows host?  Is everything on the same machine, or is there a remote machine involved in any of this?  Also, where is the "local database" running - The same WSL instance, another WSL instance, or the Windows host?

Comment: Hi @NotTheDr01ds, thanks for your comments ! You can see what happens with `ss -lt`, seems listening TCP ports need to be opened.

Comment: All the python scripts run from inside the WSL, no remote machine involved here, at least not yet. WSL is convenient for me so that I can mimic a typical cloud instance locally before deploying the scripts there. And for the local database, I did not set it up yet. Just trying the "open the doors" first with the TCP ports I would say.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using WSL2, this is a known issue. You can find a workaround and more information here:
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4150

Comment: That is only relevant when trying to access a service in WSL from a remote computer on the network.  If everything is local, then Windows and WSL2 can communicate without the need for manual port forwarding.